# What does Returning (1) during recursion accomplish?

Tags: javascript, recursion

So I'm having a really hardtime understanding recursion, I don't see how returning 1 as the final step, wraps up the following code. Why doesn't returning 1 as the final step assign "1" to the return value instead of "27"?

I tried explaining it myself writing out psuedo code, but trying made me realize I really had no idea what's going on. If besides an explaination, some psuedo code is provided, that'd be amazing. Thank you.

```js
function solveExponent(num, exp) {
    if (exp === 0) {

        // this causes the stack to well you know exceed the limit
        // letsReturnOne();

        return 1; // so i don't understand how this is any different
    }

    return num * solveExponent(num, exp - 1);
}

alert(solveExponent(3, 3));

function letsReturnOne() {
    return 1;
}

alert(letsReturnOne());
```

Comment: It will break the recursiveness of the function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have your code like this

```
if (exp === 0) {
   letsReturnOne();
}
```

The value returned from `letsReturnOne` will be returned to `solveExponent`, but since the value is ignored, `solveExponent` continue to execute the next statements in it and it would call `solveExponent` with `exp` as `-1`. From then on, the `exp` will always be negative and it will never be able to reach `0`. That is why your recursion never comes to an end.

Instead, return the value returned by `letsReturnOne()` like this

```
if (exp === 0) {
   return letsReturnOne();
}
```

Since the value returned by `letsReturnOne` is returned immediately, `solveExponent` will not execute the rest of the statements in it, when `exp` is equal to 0.

The actual recursive way in which the function evaluates your inputs is like this,

```
solveExponent(3, 3)
3 * solveExponent(3, 2)
3 * (3 * solveExponent(3, 1))
3 * (3 * (3 * solveExponent(3, 0)))
```

At this point, `exp` is `0`, so we return `1`, this is called the base case of your recursion.

```
3 * (3 * (3 * 1))
3 * (3 * 3)
3 * 9
27
```

Comment: This answer is perfect, excellently explained, it made alot more sense this morning, wish I could +1, but nonethless I accepted your answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `return` in `letsReturnOne` only return a value from `letsReturnOne`. It doesn't implicitly affect the flow inside `solveExponent`, so without that extra return, `solveExponent` just keeps on running until the last line where it calls itself again.

The call to `letsReturnOne` is just an expression that evaluates to `1`, so

```
if (exp === 0) {
   letsReturnOne();
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if (exp === 0) {
  1;
}
```

It's the difference between calling `return 1;` or just `1;`.